# try, catch handling doesn't work

Tags: exception, windows-phone

it's my first time developing windows phone app so...
I'm using try and catch in handling my exception but in the run the codes inside the try block didn't work !!

I'm sure that the inside codes are right but why it's not going inside :/
that's my code:

```
double amount =1 ;
try
{
    amount = Convert.ToDouble(textBlock1);
}
catch (Exception) { }
```

Comment: Didn't work isn't so helpful to understand the problem... What does *"didn't work"* mean?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to convert the text in textBlock1 to a double. What you are actually do is converting the TextBlock instance to a double. That doesn't make sense. This should do what you want:

```
amount = Convert.ToDouble(textBlock1.Text);
```

Understanding this problem is basic C#, so first you should learn more C# and .NET, than wp7 development will be much easier.